# Getting days difference from dates in same column in a groupby in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

| user_id | code | earliest_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | N18.1 | 2016-04-08 |
| A | N18.2 | 2017-06-08 |
| A | N18.3 | 2018-04-08 |
| B | N18.1 | 2016-06-16 |
| B | N18.2 | 2016-08-16 |
| C | N18.1 | 2021-01-11 |

In the code columns the values are always form a specified list, here [N18.1,N18.2,N18.3] etc.

I want a dataframe that displays the days it takes to progress from code N18.x to the next one in sequence for each user. I am thinking something like this:

| user_id | N18.1 -> N18.2 | N18.2 -> N18.3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 426 | 304 |
| B | 60 | n/a |
| C | n/a | n/a |

Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) for differecies per groups, create helper column for shifted `code` and pass to [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df['earliest_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['earliest_date'])

df['diff'] = df.groupby('user_id')['earliest_date'].diff().dt.days
df['code1'] = df.groupby('user_id')['code'].shift() + '->' + df['code']

df = df.pivot('user_id','code1','diff').drop(np.nan, axis=1)
print (df)
code1    N18.1->N18.2  N18.2->N18.3
user_id                            
A               426.0         304.0
B                61.0           NaN
C                 NaN           NaN
```